# How to split a variable with text content on an empty line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, file-io

how can i split a variable with text content by every empty line? Maybe into an array or something like this ...

Example:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5

line6
line7
line8
line9
```

maybe into:

```
array[0]: line1
          line2
          line3 

array[1]: line4
          line5

...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `\n\n` with something not contained in the data, set IFS to it, populate the array.

```
#! /bin/bash
in='line1
line2
line3

line4
line5

line6
line7
line8
line9'

separator=$'\xff' # or whatever char not appearing in the data

${IFS+"false"} && unset oldifs || oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$separator
arr=(${in//$'\n\n'/$separator})

${oldifs+"false"} && unset IFS || IFS="$oldifs"

printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```